# How to return specific info when a user uses CURL?

Tags: apache, curl

I am trying to figure out how to return a specific piece of information when a user uses cURL on one of my web pages(i.e. I don't want curl to download all code). I've seen a working example of this on ifconfig.me, when you curl ifconfig.me it returns only your IP address. Is this done with Apache and redirecting the cURL user-agent or accomplished somehow through PHP/HTML?

**Solved:**
Thanks to @Dancrumb for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to use Apache mod_rewrite to redirect curl user-agents to a custom page with the specific information I wanted curl to pull.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^curl/*
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ /ip.php [L]
```

Comment: What exactly your cURL output is?

Comment: Why don't you want *cURL* to download your code? Are you fine with people using LWP::UserAgent? How about wget? What about a desktop browser?

Comment: What happens when you point curl at your server?

Answer (score 1):

ifconfig.me, most likely, uses the User Agent string, in the header, to figure out that this is not a browser request.

If you execute:

```
curl ifconfig.me/ua
```

you get

```
curl/7.27.0
```

(or some other version string).

So, if you check the `User-Agent` header in the HTTP request, you can see if the request is a Curl request, a browser request or some other UA.

Comment: It's worth noting that curl can send a user agent (CURLOPT_USERAGENT), so although this is what the question is asking for it can be circumvented.

Comment: I had a feeling they were doing something like that. So I would need to use Apache to detect/redirect curl user-agents to custom page containing only the specific data I want to return?

Comment: @piddl0r yeah... relying on UA string isn't infallible, but it's a nice way to customize content

Comment: @jacobt777 You could use Apache redirects, or do the filtering in your PHP

Comment: @piddl0r good point, but for what I am trying to accomplish people would be choosing to keep the user-agent as curl and not modified. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Dancrumb, I am having trouble getting the rewrite to work in Apache, any ideas? Please see below, I'm sure I am just overlooking something...

 RewriteEngine  on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^curl/.*
 RewriteRule ^/ip\.php$ [R]

Comment: @jacobt777 Can you add that to your question, as opposed to comments, please?

Comment: @Dancrumb will do, sorry I am new to Stackoverflow. Still learning the ropes.